# How To Ignore Defalt Values of HTML Form (javascript-coder.com plugin)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, default

This i probably a very basic question but i can really use some help. I am using a plugin from javascript-coder[dot]com and can not seem to figure out how to get the script to ignore my default values upon validation. Here is the code

```
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" action="">
                    <fieldset>
                      <label>
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name:'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Name:'){this.value=''}" value="Name:" />
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <input type="text" name="Email" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email:'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email:'){this.value=''}" value="Email:"/>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <input type="text" name="Mobile Phone" />
                      </label>
                      <div class="buttons-wrapper"><a href="javascript: submitform()" class="button">Submit Info Now!</a></div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
xml:space="preserve">//<![CDATA[
//You should create the validator only after the definition of the HTML form
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("signupform");
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","req","Please enter your First Name");
frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","maxlen=20", "Max length for FirstName is 20");


frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","maxlen=50");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","req");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","email");

frmvalidator.addValidation("Mobile Phone","req");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Mobile Phone","maxlen=50");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Mobile Phone","numeric", "Please enter a valid number");


//]]></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
if(document.signupform.onsubmit())
{//this check triggers the validations
document.signupform.submit();
  }
 }
</script
```

Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: You should post at least a link to the script/plugin you're using. I assume it's [this one](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)?

Comment: I'd just replace `onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name:'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Name:'){this.value=''}" value="Name:"` with `placeholder="Name"`.